# mule getting data from json payload

Tags: xpath, groovy, mule

My payload is

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
<logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>`
```

which prints ( this is the json array input given)

[{"Name":"My name","Address":"add1","Location":"NY"}]

Now, I need to get data from the payload:

> `<logger message="#[payload.Name]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>`

it prints null. How do I get data from the payload using MEL? Is there any simpler way of getting in Groovy or xpath?

**EDIT**

Passed single json data as:

```
{"Name":"My name","Address":"add1","Location":"NY"}
```

logger:

```
  <logger message="#[payload.Name]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

it prints null value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Recent versions of Mule have [JSON Path support in MEL](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/json-module-reference#jsonpath-in-expressions), so a simple expression like `#[json:Name]` now works.

From the [MEL tips page](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Tips#MuleExpressionLanguageTips-JSONProcessing)

> MEL has no direct support for JSON. The json-to-object-transformer can turn a JSON payload into a hierarchy of simple data structures that are easily parsed with MEL.

So for your case:

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" />
<logger message="#[message.payload[0].Name]" level="INFO" />
```

I've added `[0]` because what you've shown here:

> `[{"Name":"My name","Address":"add1","Location":"NY"}]`

is not a JSON object but a JSON array containing a single JSON object.

Comment: I tried this, it still return null. I pass as a single JSON object as {"Name":"My name","Address":"add1","Location":"NY"} and used #[message.payload.Name], this too prints null.

Comment: I made it as <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.List" /> and used #[message.payload[0].Name]. that worked for me.

Comment: Strange, `returnClass="java.lang.Object"` should be able to deal with both JSON arrays (returning `java.util.List`) and JSON objects (returning `java.util.Map`). Maybe a regression?

Comment: what is this returnClass does? holds in session? returning as Object instead of List/Map and getting as payload[0] from the object will work?

Comment: `returnClass` tells the JSON deserializer what class of object it should create. When using `java.lang.Object` the deserializer picks the most appropriate type (`List` for array, `Map` for object). This flexibility is very convenient when you do not know up-front what JSON type you'll have to deal with. In your case, if you're sure you'll always get a JSON array, you can use `java.util.List`.

Answer (score 12):

In Mule ESB 3.7.0

This work:

```
#[json:Name]
```

Comment: JSON Path is definitely the way to go for recent Mule versions: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/json-module-reference#jsonpath-in-expressions